# Manipulate/rearrange intervals in R columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R with a column (sni) with numbers that looks like this etc

| bransch | sni |
| --- | --- |
| name | 15 |
| name | 15 |
| name | 16-18 |
| somename | 16-18 |
| name | 241-3 |
| someothername | 241-3 |

where I have to transform/create a new column with just one number per row, i.e. no intervals so for example it should be a new row for all individual values in the intervals and look like this

| bransch | sni |
| --- | --- |
| name | 15 |
| name | 15 |
| name | 16 |
| name | 17 |
| name | 18 |
| somename | 16 |
| somename | 17 |
| somename | 18 |
| name | 241 |
| name | 242 |
| name | 243 |
| someothername | 241 |
| someothername | 242 |
| someothername | 243 |

I'm a bit unsure which function can do this the best way, or if someone has stumble upon a similar problem/solution. Currently I have tried to split the sni column (where the "-" starts) into two new ones, but then I'm a bit stuck since I will have many rows in one of the new columns without any values etc. Also the column is a character at the moment.

Any advice?
Sincerely,
TS

Comment: In the case of `16, 17, 18`, the interval is written as `16-18` (instead of `16-8`). However, in the case of `241, 242, 243`, it is written as `241-3` instead of `241-243`. Just want to confirm whether it's a typo or it's how the actual data looks like?

Comment: No typo, actuall data but after I did some manipulations. Originally, the data looked like 24.1-3, but I don't need dots, the values are identification numbers that will be matched with other data at a later stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a while. Here is tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(sni, c("x", "y")) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(as.numeric(y)<=9, paste0(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1), y),
                                 y)) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(x,y)) %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  group_by(col2 =as.integer(gl(n(),2,n()))) %>% 
  fill(value, .direction = "down") %>% 
  complete(value = seq(first(value), last(value), by=1)) %>% 
  fill(bransch, .direction = "down") %>% 
  select(bransch, sni=value) %>% 
  group_by(col2, sni) %>% 
  slice(1)

   col2 bransch         sni
   <int> <chr>         <dbl>
 1     1 name             15
 2     2 name             15
 3     3 name             16
 4     3 name             17
 5     3 name             18
 6     4 somename         16
 7     4 somename         17
 8     4 somename         18
 9     5 name            241
10     5 name            242
11     5 name            243
12     6 someothername   241
13     6 someothername   242
14     6 someothername   243
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There are however some other columns in the data frame that I need to keep.

Comment: This should be no problem. Just modify the select line:-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this.

Assume only three digits interval would have the pattern of `123-5` instead of `123-125`, therefore in the `ifelse`, we modify this special pattern (e.g. `123-5`) of interval into more regular one (`123-125`). Then separate the interval to individual integer using `separate_rows`.

We can then use `complete` to fill in the missing sequence in the interval.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(sni,bransch) %>% 
  mutate(sni2 = ifelse(grepl("-", sni) & nchar(sub("-.*$", "", sni)) >= 3, 
                       sub("^(\\d\\d)(.)-", "\\1\\2-\\1", sni), 
                       sni)) %>% 
  separate_rows(sni2, convert = T) %>%
  complete(sni2 = min(sni2):max(sni2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-sni)

# A tibble: 14 × 2
   bransch        sni2
   <chr>         <int>
 1 name             15
 2 name             15
 3 name             16
 4 name             17
 5 name             18
 6 somename         16
 7 somename         17
 8 somename         18
 9 name            241
10 name            242
11 name            243
12 someothername   241
13 someothername   242
14 someothername   243
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly

```
tmp=setNames(strsplit(df$sni,"-"),df$bransch)
tmp=unlist(
  lapply(tmp,function(x){
    x=as.numeric(x)
    if (length(x)>1) {
      if (x[1]<x[2]) {
        seq(x[1],x[2],1)
      } else {
        seq(x[1],x[1]+x[2]-1,1)
      }
    } else {
      x
    }
  })
)

data.frame(
  "bransch"=names(tmp),
  "sni"=tmp
)

          bransch sni
1            name  15
2            name  15
3           name1  16
4           name2  17
5           name3  18
6       somename1  16
7       somename2  17
8       somename3  18
9           name1 241
10          name2 242
11          name3 243
12 someothername1 241
13 someothername2 242
14 someothername3 243
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The values 1-3 doesn't have to be added to the names(but I guess its fine). Also, I do have several other columns in the data frame, but didn't mention them here since I thought it doesn't matter? Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

Using separate to get the start and end of the sequence, the we can map and unnest to get the result.

```
library (tidyverse) 
 data %>%
        separate(
        sni, 
        into = c("from", "to"),
        fill = "right",
        convert = TRUE) %>%
        mutate(to = if_else(is.na(to), from, to)) %>%
        transmute(
        bransch,
        sni = map2(from, to, `:`)) %>%
        unnest_longer(sni)

# A tibble: 14 x 2
   bransch         sni
   <chr>         <int>
 1 name             15
 2 name             15
 3 name             16
 4 name             17
 5 name             18
 6 some name        16
 7 some name        17
 8 some name        18
 9 name            241
10 name            242
11 name            243
12 someothername   241
13 someothername   242
14 someothername   243
```

## Data

```
data <- tibble(
bransch = c("name","name","name","some name","name","someothername"),
sni =c("15","15","16-18","16-18","241-243","241-243"))
```